# Discontinuities in Phase response calculation of FIR filter

Tags: matlab, math, signal-processing, octave

I'm trying to perform a relatively simple task - I have a digital filter implemented on an embedded system, and I'd like to generate the data to describe its magnitude and phase response vs. frequency.

I have been able to successfully generate the magnitude data using a number of methods, but am having trouble with the phase.

In octave, I've generated the magnitude and frequency response plots using the function freqz as follows:

```
freqz_plot(W_hz, H, 0)
```

In this case, W_hz is a vector of frequency data in Hz, and H is the computed response of the filter (i.e., the complex value evaluated at each frequency).

I get the following plots, which look like what I expect for the chosen filter design:
[image: freqz plots]

However, if I manually compute the phase data using the following formula:

```
phase_deg = rad2deg(angle(H));
```

I get this plot instead, full of large discontinuities (forgive the lack of axis labels, I was rushing, its phase in deg vs. frequency in hz):

[image: manually calculated phase in deg vs. frequency in hz]

I can't figure out the math regarding how to correctly eliminate the discontinuities and reproduce the plots that freqz generates. I can see that some of the discontinuities are 180deg and some are 90deg, but I can't figure how to correctly determine the size/direction of the discontinuities and account for it properly in the calculation so that I can generate the data myself.

Thanks!

Comment: It is just that freqz understands that signal phase is continuous when the amplitude is non-zero and so instead of flipping to +180 every time it remains continuous until the amplitude response reaches (near) to zero and then it flips at about 80Hz.

Comment: but how does it reconstruct the continuous signal then? How is it able to determine between "real" discontinuities, of which there are many, from those that need to be eliminated to restore continuity? 

What do you mean "continuous when the amplitude is non-zero"? the magnitude data is non-zero? the magnitude is non-zero and positive everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out - the answer lies in the explanation of the unwrap function, which successfully generates the expected continuous phase data:

Q = unwrap(P) unwraps the radian phase angles in a vector P. Whenever the jump between consecutive angles is greater than or equal to π radians, unwrap shifts the angles by adding multiples of ±2π until the jump is less than π

In usage, for example:

phase_deg_2 = rad2deg(unwrap(angle(H)));

where H is the computed frequency response of the filter as described above